# Maintaining Two Sets of Models: Angular and WebAPI2

Tags: angular, model, asp.net-web-api2

I have just start out with Angular and have come across a challenge of maintaining two sets of models from the front-end vs back-end. What methods or automated tools exist for maintaining the code bases (property definitions) of the models between two distinct projects, in my case Angular and WebAPI2? I can imagine for large projects that this will be a problem and should be automated.

Comment: It's my choice, I use vs2017 for Angular(front-end) and WebAPIs(back-end). vs2017 is powerful for maintaining both and have templates for jump start.

Comment: Let say there is tool that will sync your typescript model with your web api model then will you look for a tool that will write logic also? Let suppose you added a property and that property is only have significance for your server thing. Will this property also sync? There are numerous conditions will arise.

Answer (score 0):

If you are lazy to write again then you can you use online tools that will convert json to typescript interface. visit this website http://json2ts.com/